# how to transfer from MySql to Management Studio

Tags: mysql, sql, management-studio-express

I have database which works on MySql. And i need to copy it to another computer where there is only management studio. i create .sql file from MySql and tried to run it in studio but always have syntax errors.
How to do it correctly?

```
 CREATE TABLE branches (
  idbranches int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  address varchar(200) NOT NULL,
```

e.g. incorrect syntax for "AUTO_INCREMENT"

Comment: The DBMS behind that "Management Studio", which at any rate is just a client (if this really means Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio Express as tagged, which is quite archaic, it might be better to use the latest version of the fully blown SQL Server Management Studio instead, which is also free nowadays), is an SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server syntax is:

```
CREATE TABLE branches (
  idbranches int identity(1, 1) not null,
  address varchar(200) NOT NULL
);
```